# Mentioning a user in Input.Text field of Adaptive card (C#)

Tags: c#, json, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I want to mention a user in Input.Text field of Adaptive Card. Whenever we type "@" in Input.Text, I want a list of all the members of channel to appear like in a normal mention. Is this possible?

Currently the mention feature is not working.

Code of my Adaptive Card -

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.2",
  "speak": "Your  meeting about \"Adaptive Card design session\" is starting at ${formatDateTime(start.dateTime, 'HH:mm')}pmDo you want to snooze  or do you want to send a late notification to the attendees?",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Input.Text",
          "id": "comment",
          "placeholder": "Please Enter Your Comment"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Comment",
      "data": {
        "x": "comment"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The card looks like this:
[image: The card looks like this]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Teams. To make a feature request, please contact Teams support directly. You can do this through the Teams app or by posting an issue in the Teams docs repo: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues